# Change product.info.container view for bundle products only

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Case:

For bundle products I would like to change/override the order of the option wrapper, I'm using the rwd theme and changed the order in the local.xml so product.info.options.wrapper.bottom get's loaded before product.info.options.wrapper and this works fine however I would like to change this for bundle products only.

changed local.xml:

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
 <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key>value>container1</value></action>
 <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
 <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
 <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
</block>
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
 <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
 <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
 <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
 <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
```

I would like to use this config only for the bundle products so I've tried bundle.xml but when I insert this in the

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
 <reference name="product.info">
```

area it's loaded twice. How should I override the local.xml setting for bundle products only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap around each of your block types with the following, you will need to have one for bundles and one for everything else

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="catalog">
```

close it with

```
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```